# Lista Circular Duplamente encadeada em C/C++

Tags: c, c++, lista, lista-encadeada, referência-circular

Estou com problemas para remover o primeiro e o ultimo elemento desta lista circular.

```
// Created by Thiago Cunha on 25/05/2017.
//

#include "double_linked_list_circular.h"

int count = 0;

List* init() {
    return NULL;
}

List* insertInit(List* list, int data) {

    List* temp = (List *) malloc (sizeof(List));
    temp->data = data;

    if (isEmpty(list)) {
        temp->previous = temp;
        temp->next = temp;
        return temp;
    }

    temp->next = list;
    temp->previous = list->previous;
    list->previous->next = temp;
    list->previous = temp;
    list = temp;

    return list;

}

List* insertFinish(List* list, int data) {

    List* temp = (List *) malloc (sizeof(List));
    temp->data = data;


    if (isEmpty(list)) {
        temp->previous = temp;
        temp->next = temp;
        return temp;
    }

    temp->next = list;
    list->previous->next = temp;
    temp->previous = list->next;
    list->previous = temp;

    return list;

}

void displayInit(List* list) {
    cout << "Display Init: " << list->data << endl;
}

void displayFinish(List* list) {
    cout << "Display finish: " << list->previous->data << endl;

}

void display(List* list) {

    if (isEmpty(list)) {
        cout << "Your list is empty." << endl;
        return;
    }

    List* p = list;
    cout << "[ ";
    do {
        cout << p->data << " ";
        p = p->next;
    } while (p != list);
    cout << " ]" << endl << endl;

}

List* removeInit(List* list) {




}

List* removeFinish(List* list) {



}


bool isEmpty(List* list) {
    return list == NULL;
}

int size() {
    return count;
}

void toIncrease() {
    ++count;
}

void toDesincrease() {
    --count;
}
```

Comment: Normalmente, listas circulares não trabalham muito com o conceito de posicionamento absoluto, como _primeiro_ e _último_

Comment: O que você já tentou? Que erro recebeu? A idéia é *pular* o item a ser excluído antes antes de dar um `free`. Se `count == 1` você aponta a lista para `NULL`, caso contrário, `previousElem->next = current->next` e  `nextElement->previous = current->previous`. Tendo implementado `removeInit`, `removeFinish`é muito semelhante, só que você começa de `current->previous`.

Comment: Eu recomendo você começar essa implementação com a função `removeElemento(List *elemento_a_ser_removido)`, para depois implementar a remoção "começo" e do "final" sobre essa função

Comment: Resultado:

[ 40 30 20 10 50 60 70  ]

Display Init: 40
Display finish: 70

removeFinish(List* list);
[ 40 30  ]

Comment: `List* removeFinish(List* list) {

    if (isEmpty(list)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    List* p = list->previous;
    list->previous = p->previous;
    list->previous->next = list;

    free(p);

    return list;

}`

Comment: @ThiagoCunha , coloque isso na pergunta, porque fica melhor de se ler e, também, melhora a qualidade da publicação

Comment: Consegui aqui! Graças a Deus!
Estava com problemas na inserção do fim...
por isso, por incrível que possa parecer, o problema aconteceu no remove fim. Segue código abaixo:
https://github.com/codenome/double-circular-linked-list

Comment: @ThiagoCunha já que encontrou a solução, você pode responder sua própria pergunta. Essa é uma boa forma de contribuir com o site.

Comment: Obrigado @Knautiluz!
Respondi a solução logo abaixo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema de remoção do último elemento.

```
List* removeFinish(List* list) {

if (isEmpty(list)) {
    return NULL;
}

if ( (list->previous == list) && (list->next == list) ) {
    free(list);
    return NULL;
}

List* p = list->previous;
p->previous->next = list;
list->previous = p->previous;

free(p);

cout << "Data was removed with successfully!" << endl;

return list;
}
```

[Para acessar o código inteiro, vem comigo neste link e não deixe de marcar sua estrelinha no Github!](https://github.com/codenome/double-circular-linked-list)

Comment: Ri muito do "vem comigo neste link"!!!

Comment: Achei muito estranho você misturar C++ (`cout`) com C (`free`). Não que isso esteja errado, mas o melhor é sempre tentar usar o máximo o que a linguagem lhe fornece. Se não me engano, para liberar memória no C++ é `delete`

Comment: RSRSR... Eu também! Nem sei se pode fazer distrações assim ao responder. Mas agradeço! :)

Comment: dar um ar humorístico à postagem é uma questão estilística. Eu por exemplo fiz isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/248505/64969), mais para tentar passar uma lição do que por outro motivo. Havendo o conteúdo correto da resposta, não vejo muita ofensa em dar esse toque estilístico na forma da resposta. PS: o toque de humor que eu usei foi para tentar me controlar e não xingar o AP ;-)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado. Obrigado pela observação! Então, seguindo o termo de boas práticas, é errado! Mas existem injeções de C dentro do C++ que pode cobrir isso, que é uma boa prática de desempenho na hora de misturar as sintaxes.
Estou aprendendo C++ um pouco mais a fundo. Mas a liberação de memória esta funcionando mesmo assim! O importante é que a minha gambiarra funcionou!

Comment: Funciona sim, porque você alocou com recursos C (`malloc` e família, no caso você usou só o `malloc`). É uma questão de o quanto a linguagem pode fazer por você. Nesse sentido, C é muito cru, não te dá suporte em nada, já C++ dá muito mais suporte do que se está acostumado. Tem umas paradas com coleta de lixo com ponteiros inteligentes que creio que libera a memória por você. Vale a pena tentar =)

Comment: Veja mais: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/248539/64969