# Qual tipo de ponteiro inteligente escolher?

Tags: c++, ponteiro, memória, c++11, smart-pointer

Como saber qual o tipo de ponteiro inteligente para usar?

E qual a diferença entre eles?

Exemplo:

```
std::unique_ptr<MinhaClasse> mClasse(new MinhaClasse)
std::shared_ptr<MinhaClasse> mClasse(new MinhaClasse)
std::auto_ptr<MinhaClasse> mClasse(new MinhaClasse)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O [`auto_ptr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto_ptr) foi marcado como obsoleto no C++11 e removido no C++17.

`unique_ptr` e `shared_ptr` são complementares.

O `unique_ptr` só permite que um ponteiro por vez aponte para o recurso administrado (i.e., você não pode copiar o ponteiro):

```
unique_ptr<T> myPtr(new MinhaClasse); // Ok
unique_ptr<T> myOtherPtr = myPtr; // Erro: Não pode copiar um unique_ptr
```

Já um `shared_ptr` pode ser compartilhado, internamente ele usa um contador de referências e só destroi o recurso quando o último ponteiro é destruído.

```
shared_ptr<T> myPtr(new MinhaClasse); // Ok
shared_ptr<T> myOtherPtr = myPtr; // Dois ponteiros para o mesmo recurso
```

---

**Fonte:** [SOen - Differences between unique_ptr and shared_ptr [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6876833/664577)

Answer (score 6):

> Qual a diferença entre eles?

Cada um dos ponteiro inteligente fornece uma variação das regras de posse do recurso sendo manipulado. Por exemplo, um ponteiro inteligente que tem posse sem compartilhamento manipula o recurso de um modo que nenhum outro ponteiro inteligente possa ter posse compartilhada do mesmo recurso. Já ponteiros inteligentes com posse compartilhada permitem que mais de um ponteiro inteligente manipule o mesmo recurso ao mesmo tempo.

**Nota**: irei omitir as vantagens de um ponteiro inteligente sobre um ponteiro primitivo, já que essa discussão não cabe nessa thread.

Vamos as diferenças:

### 1. `std::unique_ptr`: Posse única

Um [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) gerencia um recurso através de um ponteiro e descarta desse recurso quando a instância do `std::unique_ptr` sai de escopo (ou quando `.reset()` é chamado.)

Esse *smart pointer* implementa as regras de **posse única**. Isto é, não é possível copiar um `std::unique_ptr`, assim fazendo com que o recurso mantenha-se único ao `std::unique_ptr` original. Você pode, entretanto, **transferir a posse** desse recurso para outro `std::unique_ptr`, deixando o smart pointer original vazio (ou seja, sem um recurso para gerenciar.)

Por exemplo:

```
auto p1 = std::make_unique<int>(42); // `std::make_unique` é C++14.
//std::unique_ptr<int> p2 = p1; // Errado: não é possível copiar um `std::unique_ptr`.
std::unique_ptr<int> p3 = std::move(p1); // Ok: posse do recurso foi transferida.
```

No exemplo acima, a variável `p1` é um `std::unique_ptr<int>`, que gerencia um ponteiro de `int` pra uma memória dinâmica.

Na segunda linha (comentada), tentar copiar um `std::unique_ptr` é inválido e o compilador reclamará (i.e. o código não irá compilar). Isso é proposital: o copy-constructor do `std::unique_ptr` é [implicitamente declarado como deletado](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr.single.ctor).

Já na terceira linha, em vez de uma cópia, temos a transferência da posse do ponteiro. Ao chamar [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) com a variável `p1`, estamos dizendo que *" `p1` pode ser movido, ou seja, seus recursos podem ser transferidos"*. Isso é importante, pois agora é o move-constructor que será chamado. Ele irá copiar o ponteiro gerenciado por `p1` e anulá-lo em seguida. O código seguinte demonstra esse efeito:

```
assert(p3.get() != nullptr); // `p3` toma posse do recurso gerenciado por `p1`.
assert(*p3 == 42);
assert(p1.get() == nullptr); // `p1` agora não gerencia recurso algum.
```

### 2. `std::shared_ptr`: Posse compartilhada

Um [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) também gerencia um recurso através de um ponteiro, com a diferença de que **instâncias de `std::shared_ptr` podem ser copiadas**. Chamamos isso de **posse compartilhada**. Esse smart pointer só descarta do recurso se ele for o único que está em posse do mesmo.

Quando acontece uma cópia desse smart pointer, um contador de referências (i.e. o número de smart pointers compartilhando o mesmo recurso) é incrementado. Quando um dos smart pointers sai de escopo, ou `.reset()` é chamado nele, esse contador é decrementado, mas o recurso continua vivo. O recurso só morre quando a contagem de posses compartilhadas chega a zero.

Por exemplo:

```
{
  auto s1 = std::make_shared<int>(42);

  {
    // Ok: a cópia significa compartilhamento do mesmo recurso. Contador incrementa.
    std::shared_ptr<int> s2 = s1;
  } // s2 sai de escopo e o contador decrementa.

} // s1 sai de escopo, contador decrementa e descarta o recurso.
```

Uma funcionalidade que `std::shared_ptr` tem é de poder compartilhar um mesmo recurso, porém apontar para um lugar totalmente diferente. Esse é o *aliasing constructor*. Ele permite que possamos construir um `std::shared_ptr` que compartilha posse com um outro `std::shared_ptr`, porém tendo um valor de ponteiro diferente:

```
struct S
{
  int i;
  float f;
  S(int i, float f) : i(i), f(f) {}
};

auto s = std::make_shared<S>(42, 3.14f);

// Esses dois `shared_ptr`s seguintes compartilham o mesmo
// recurso do `s`, só que eles apontam pra lugares diferentes.
std::shared_ptr<int> si(s, &s->i);
std::shared_ptr<float> sf(s, &s->f);

// Ao de-referenciá-los, acessamos os membros do `s`.
assert(*si == 42);
assert(*sf == 3.14f);
```

Como a posse ainda é do mesmo recurso, o contador de referências funciona igual. Ou seja, esse `S` só vai ser descartado quando todos os `std:shared_ptr`s soltarem a posse.

### 3. `std::weak_ptr`: Posse compartilhada fraca

Ainda temos o ponteiro inteligente [std::weak_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr). Esse aqui anda de mãos dadas com o `std::shared_ptr`. Um `std::weak_ptr` é um smart pointer que mantém uma referência **sem posse** de um recurso gerenciado por um `std::shared_ptr`.

A ideia do `std::weak_ptr` é implementar uma posse temporária do recurso de um `std::shared_ptr`. Ele observa esse recurso sem interferir na vida dele. Para acessá-lo, esse `std::weak_ptr` é convertido pra um `std::shared_ptr` pra poder ter uma posse temporária do recurso. Isso é útil para quando você quiser acessar um recurso apenas se ele estiver disponível.

### 4. `std::observer_ptr`: Nenhuma posse (library fundamentals TS v2)

O ponteiro *burro* [std::observer_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) segura um ponteiro primitivo **sem posse alguma** do recurso desse ponteiro. Ele é só um observador e não é responsável pelo gerenciamento do recurso.

`std::observer_ptr` não existe em nenhuma revisão anterior ou em C++17. Ele faz parte da proposta [library fundamentals TS v2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4562.html) e *talvez* pode ser adicionado em C++20.

> Como saber qual o tipo de ponteiro inteligente usar?

Quando você tem um recurso e só quer que ele seja gerenciado automaticamente (i.e. não existe nenhum outro requerimento não-trivial e só quer ter seu tempo de vida manipulado automaticamente), `std::unique_ptr` então é suficiente. A maioria dos casos se encaixam aqui. E, realmente, usar `new` e `delete` em códigos normais é desencorajado, sendo recomendado usar `std::unique_ptr` no lugar.

Para recursos com necessidades especiais, como recursos usados entre várias threads, então `std::shared_ptr` servirá muito bem, já que seu propósito principal é tornar seguro o compartilhamento de recursos entre códigos concorrentes. Lembre-se: `std::shared_ptr` tem um custo por essa segurança. O seu contador de referências é atômico<sup>1</sup>, tornando cópias mais caras (lentas). Se você precisa compartilhar a posse de um recurso em um código não-concorrente ou não-paralelo, aconselho aderir a outros ponteiros inteligentes.

Já `std::weak_ptr` é útil para impedir referências circulares entre `std::shared_ptr`s. Pode acontecer casos em que uma classe `Foo` pode ter posse de uma classe `Bar`, e ao mesmo tempo `Bar` ter posse sobre `Foo`. Nessa situação, um mantém o outro vivo, o contador nunca chega a zero e ninguém é descartado no fim. Aí acontece vazamento de memória, já que os recursos não são liberados. Um `std::weak_ptr` quebra esse ciclo, já que você só tem posse do recurso depois de acessá-lo (e essa posse é temporária).

Um ponteiro como `std::observer_ptr` não tem uma utilidade aparente a primeira vista. Porém, seu único propósito é ser uma alternativa para ponteiros primitivos que são usados para o mesmo propósito: apenas observar um recurso sem ter posse ou responsabilidade alguma sobre o mesmo. Ele é um tipo vocabulário e serve apenas para mostrar a intenção do ponteiro sem precisar analisar a fundo o código.

Temos ainda mais um ponteiro inteligente [std::atomic_shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/atomic_shared_ptr) sendo proposto para C++ ([Concurrency TS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/concurrency)). Um `std::atomic_shared_ptr` é apenas um `std::shared_ptr` com uma interface melhor que as [funções livres](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) pra fazer operações atômicas com o recurso em posse.

---

<sup>1</sup> Dependendo da implementação, a operação de incrementar/decrementar o contador não é atômica se o programa não fazer uso de threads (i.e. não compilar com `-pthread`). Mas não assuma que esse é o caso para todas as implementações.

Answer (score 4):

Complementando a resposta do Anthony Accioly que já responde bem o perguntado, note que o fato dos ponteiros serem inteligentes não quer dizer que não precise ter alguma coordenação sua no uso deles. C++, ao contrário de Rusto, por exemplo, não controla o tempo de vida do objeto no momento da compilação e se você chamar uma função que mate um objeto e tentar usá-lo depois de chamar essa função pode ter problemas. Você ainda precisa ter controle do tempo de vida objeto, só não precisa se preocupar tanto quanto com ponteiros brutos. É muito mais difícil errar sem querer.

O `unique_ptr` é sempre o preferido porque ele tem abstração zero, ou seja, não consome memória, nem tempo de processamento. Só quando realmente precisa de compartilhamento do objeto é que deve optar pelo `shared_ptr` que tem custo de memória e processamento, pesado se em uso concorrente. É possível transformar um objeto `unique_ptr` em `shared_ptr`, o contrário com limitação.